# What does "take a lap out of each day" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does the "lap out" mean??

> I'd highly recommend for you to get out there and film your riding. Everyone has access to a video camera these days whether it's a Gopro or just the camera on your smart phone.Go up with a buddy, **take a lap out of each day**      and file each other so you can go home and see what you look like.This is going to do wonders for your riding. You will pick up so much stuff that you did not realize was happening and you can compare your riding to mine or other pros that you want to ride like.

PS: https://tw.voicetube.com/videos/31641#video-container   <-- I've studying for this web site.the question sentence is between 0:56 and 0:68

please give me more sentences, thanks?

Comment: What is the source? "a lap out of each day" and "file each other" don't make sense without some context.

Comment: Again, what is the source? There seems to be several grammatical errors, so I don't think this is a good example for language learning.

Comment: @user3169 I've put the reference website to question content , thank again

Comment: @user3169 this resource is from English Leaning Website which is for local pupil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm expanding the comment I made above.  Note that this source is not particularly idiomatic or even correct English, so it's not necessarily a good guide for learning colloquial expressions.

That said, you're being confused by thinking that "lap out" is an expression: it is not.  The expression you need to understand is **take [a time period] out of each day**.  For example, I might write:

> Take ten minutes out of each day to practice your vocabulary.

This just says that you should stop doing everything else for ten minutes every day and devote that ten minutes to doing a particular thing (practicing your vocabulary).

In your example, the time period you're being asked to reserve is **one [lap](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lap)**, which means "a complete circuit of a course in racing." If you're out snowboarding with a friend, you are both going to do multiple **laps** of the snowboarding course throughout the day.  Note that this is not really colloquial - usually you do **runs** in snowboarding, not **laps**, because a **lap** is almost always a circular route.

This video is advising you to **take one lap out of each day**.  That is, stop snowboarding for one lap (or run) and instead, video your friend doing his lap (or run).  I am sure that "file each other" is a mistake and it should be "**film** each other".  If you both do this for each other, you will each have a video of your performance to review for style and technique.